# Find the value for $\Sigma_1^{\infty} \frac{n}{2^n}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, power-series

I am messing around with series and trying to figure out how to calculate the sum. I know that $\Sigma_0^{\infty} x^n$ for $-1<x<1$ converges to $\dfrac{1}{1-x}$ = $1 + x + x^2 + x^3 +...+ x^n$. Term by term differentiation yields $\dfrac{1}{(1-x)^2}=1+2x+3x^2+4x^3+...+nx^{n-1}$. I found that if I let $x=\frac{1}{2}$ I get $1+1+\frac{3}{4}+\frac{4}{8}+...+ = \Sigma_0^{\infty}\dfrac{n}{2^{n-1}}$

This is not quite what I want but I am having trouble figuring out how to fix it.

Comment: `I found that ...` That's precisely twice the sum you are after.

Comment: Just multiply $1/2$ both sides in your last series!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiplying both sides by $x$ gets you $\sum_{0}^{\infty}nx^{n}=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}$

You want the series to begin from index $n=1$, you can also drop the first element (since it's equal to $0$)

$\sum_{1}^{\infty}nx^{n}=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}$

Now you can plug in $x=1/2$

Comment: Okay that makes sense.  The series I came up with sums to 4 and this one sums to 2. So simple, I can't see how I missed it.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with,

$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{n}{2^{n-1}}=4$$

Multiply by $\frac{1}{2}$,

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2} \dfrac{n}{2^{n-1}}=2$$

Because the $n=0$ term is $0$ we may drop it to get,

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{2^n}=2$$

Answer (score 2):

$1/2 + 2/4 + 3/8 + 4/16 + 5/32 + 6/64 + 7/128 + …$

$= (1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + 1/16 + 1/32 + …) + (1/4 + 1/8 + /1/16 + 1/32 + …) + (1/8 + 1/16 + 1/32 + …) + … $

$= (1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + 1/16 + 1/32 + …) + 1/2.(1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + 1/16 + 1/32 + …) + $

$1/4.(1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + 1/16 + 1/32 + …) + 1/8.(1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + 1/16 + 1/32 + …) + …$

$= (1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + 1/16 + 1/32 + …) .(1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + 1/16 + 1/32 + …)$

$= 1 . 2$

$= 2.$